# GDataXML/Libxml2 XPath concat doesn't work

Tags: iphone, xml, xpath, libxml2

I'm using [GDataXML](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml) (uses libxml2 in background) on the iPhone to read a list of names from a XML-File.

```
<persons>
    <person id=1>
       <firstname>John<firstname>
       <lastname>Doe<lastname>
    </person>
</persons>
```

But when i try to concat first and lastname with

```
/persons/person/concat(firstname, ' ', lastname)
```

it doesn't work with GDataXML. When trying the same with example with the .NET XML libary or testing it with AquaPath it works.

Any hints or other alternatives to get it working?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation and for a complete solution. :)

Comment: [AquaPath](http://ditchnet.org/aquapath/) is an XPath 2.0 evaluator.

Answer (score 1):

> But when i try to concat first and
>   lastname with
>
> ```
> /persons/person/concat(firstname, ' ', lastname)
> ```
>
> it doesn't work with GDataXML.

**LibXML is only implementing XPath 1.0**.

The above expression is not syntactically correct in XPath 1.0 (it is a correct XPath 2.0 expression).

> When
>   trying the same with example with the
>   .NET XML libary or testing it with
>   AquaPath it works.

**You are mistaken about .NET XML** (unless you are using a 3rd party XPath 2.0 processor such as Saxon, Altova or XQSharp) -- **.NET does not implement XPath 2.0**.

**Solution**:

Use the following XPath 1.0 expression:

```
concat(/*/*/firstname, ' ', /*/*/lastname)
```

Comment: @Dimitre: Also, just in this case, with an XML tree provider preserving white space only text nodes, `normalize-space(/persons/person[1])` will work.

Comment: @Dimitrie: doesn't work for me...also doesn't work in AquaPath and with my Chrome XML extension...i always get ´Error: INVALID_EXPRESSION_ERR: DOM XPath Exception 51`

Comment: @staeff: In case you get such an error message this means that your copy/paste was incorrect and didn't exactly copy the expression. The XPath expression from my answer is valid both in XPath 1.0 and XPath 2.0.

Comment: @Alejandro: Your proposed expression relies on the relative order of elements and on a `person` not having any other children elements.

Comment: @Dimitre: You are right. That's why I say `"just in this case"`. About the error message: Do note that your expression isn't valid XPath 2.0 if there are more than one `person` element. AquaPath is an XPath 2.0 evaluator.

Comment: @Alejandro: When I am saying this is valid XPath 2.0 expression, I mean, of course, when applied on the provided XPM document.

Comment: @staeff: In case you get such an error message this means that your copy/paste was incorrect and didn't exactly copy the expression. The XPath expression from my answer is valid both in XPath 1.0 and XPath 2.0. Another possibility is that you were using XPath 2.0 engine with an XML document, different than the one you provided in your question.

Comment: @dimitre: i'm using this xpath expression: `concat(/lehrer/klassen/klasse/schuelerliste/schueler/vname, ' ', /lehrer/klassen/klasse/schuelerliste/schueler/nname)` when i try both of them separatly they work.